# How to use newer not stable yet version of symfony?

Tags: composer-php

Currently I use `5.2.3` version of Symfony. I want to use feature from this pull request https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/36851. It's rather github / composer related question rather than symfony itself. How to do it?

So far I try:

```
{
    ...
    "symfony/form": "5.2.*-dev", // changes I made to composer.json
    ...
}
```

The composer update end successfully:

```
  - Upgrading symfony/form (v5.2.4 => 5.2.x-dev 7664ad9): Extracting archive
```

But still If I use `choice_translation_parameters` in code I get:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ...
        $builder->add('amount', ChoiceType::class, ["label" => "rese.amount?", "choices" => $roomAmountChoices, "choice_translation_parameters" => []]);
        ...
    }
```

> An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType": The option "choice_translation_parameters" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_file_upload", "attr", "attr_translation_parameters", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "block_prefix", "by_reference", "choice_attr", "choice_filter", "choice_label", "choice_loader", "choice_name", "choice_translation_domain", "choice_value", "choices", "compound", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "ea_crud_form", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "expanded", "getter", "group_by", "help", "help_attr", "help_html", "help_translation_parameters", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "is_empty_callback", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "label_html", "label_translation_parameters", "mapped", "method", "multiple", "placeholder", "post_max_size_message", "preferred_choices", "property_path", "required", "row_attr", "setter", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message".

Comment: From the pop-up text for the [tag:git] tag: "Also, do not use this tag for general programming questions that happen to involve a Git repository." (I snipped off the tag)

Comment: @torek sorry about that. I just put `git` thinking is the right thing to do.

Comment: @yivi, but I am pretty sure `symfony`, `symfony-forms` tags are right.

Comment: No, your issue is not related to symfony or symfony-forms, is simply how to use composer to ask for a specific branch.

Comment: @yivi okey then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You (in this example me, because i answer to my own question ) do everything right, just pick wrong branch. Change it to:

```
{
    ...
    "symfony/form": "5.*-dev",
    ...
}
```

If you take a closer look on `symfony/form` repository history you notice that previously `composer` pick branch which doesn't include commit with feature you request.

Answer (score 0):

Using `*-dev` isn't going to work because the code is still waiting to be merged into `symfony/symfony`.

Take a look at http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/php/have-composer-use-development-branches/ for instructions how to override a package with a different repository.

In your case the composer.json would have:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/VincentLanglet/symfony.git"
    }
]
```

Warning: This will be good for short periods of time but going into production with this is risky. You will get the feature you want but are relying on the author to keep updated with the real symfony master.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an open (unmerged) branch, you can not directly pull it. You have to get this registered in your `composer.json` using repository pattern.

Something similar to

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/VincentLanglet/symfony.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "symfony/form": "^5.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Silly question to ask, but... this https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/38469 didn't end by merge to symfony:5.x?